# Bypass dok_matrix.get type checking

Tags: python, performance, scipy, sparse-matrix

16% of the running time of my program is spent inside the `isintlike()` function from `scipy/sparse/sputils`. All of the calls to `isintlike()` come from calls to `dok_matrix.get()` (which make up 20% of the running time). I know that the indices I'm calling `get()` with are ints, so i don't actually need type checking.

I tried to bypass it by using `x[coords]` instead of `x.get(coords)`, but this actually slowed down my program. I'm guessing it's calling `get()` behind the scenes with added overhead.

I'm not planning on reducing the number of calls to `dok_matrix.get()`, so this is the bottleneck for now. Is there any way to bypass this type checking?

Comment: `dok` is a sublclass of `dict`.  Its `update` method is disabled, but there is a backdoor `_update` that operates without checking.  I'd suggest reading the `dok_matrix` class code.  Use these backdoors at your own risk.  In general, sparse code that depends heavily on iteration, even with the `dok` format, is poorly written.

Comment: If depending heavily on iteration is poor writing, what would be good alternatives ? i can see maybe batching the results, but i guess there's other things to do

Comment: The `sparse` package originally used the `coo` and `csr/csc` formats, using formats and methods developed for linear algebra problems.  So matrix multiplication and linear equation solution are reasonably fast (if sparse enough).  `dok` (and `lil`) was added primarily as a faster way of setting individual elements.  For math it needs to be converted to `csr`.  But if you aren't doing that kind of math, a plain Python dictionary (or default dict) might be just as convenient, and faster.

Comment: MATLAB's sparse matrix code uses the `csc` format.  I used it years ago for finite element modeling.  The `scipy` extensions to other formats has been driven, I think, by the needs of the natural language and machine learning users.  `scikit-learn` for example has added some of its own sparse utilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the `dict` base class method directly, bypassing the type checking:

```
dict.get(dok_matrix, coords)
```

Comment: This returns `None` is `coords` is not found.